# Remove mentions except mentions that related to keyword in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a tweet :

> I playing with @mention1, @mention2 and @mention3 in the field

How to remove *@mention1* and *@mention2* but keep **@mention3** because it related to keyword?

Thank you. :-)

Comment: `@mention[12]` is probably a good start.

Comment: What is the result after the removal?

Comment: Result : " I playing with ,  and  in the field "
. Here my pattern :
 (@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|((?!(@mention3))\b\w+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a one-line workaround along these lines:

```
s = re.sub(r'KEEPME', '@mention3', re.sub(r'@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '', re.sub(r'@mention3', 'KEEPME', 'I playing with @mention1, @mention2 and @mention3 in the field')))
```

if I understood your problem properly?

And I'd just make sure to use a unique string that won't appear in the real tweet, instead of 'KEEPME'.